# HTTPBuilder adds valuecount,strings, bytes into request body and the other side can't parse that JSON

Tags: json, groovy, httpbuilder, gstring

I need to send request with groovy HTTPBuilder, here is code:

```java
String authToken = "token"
def cfManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()
def addressJira = "http://xxx"
def http = new HTTPBuilder("${address}")
    
    http.setClient(HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig).build())
    try {
        http.request(POST, ContentType.JSON) {            
            headers.'Authorization' = "token ${authToken}"
            headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'           
            headers.'cache-control' = 'no-cache'            
  body = [
          "request": [
           "token":"${authToken}",
            "commonData":[
              "taskId":"${issue.id.toString()}"
           ],                    
            "phonesData":[
             "phone":"${cfManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_xxx")?.getValue(issue)?.toString()}",                        
             "phoneType": 1
            ],
             "addData": [
              "title":"${issue.summary.toString()}",
              "description":"${issue.description.toString()}"
             ]
          ]
         ]   
  requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
            
  response.success = { resp, json ->
   log.info("Resp status  " + resp.status.toString())
   log.info("JSON ${json.toString()}")
   log.info("JSON text ${json.text}")
  }

   response.failure = { resp ->
    log.warn("response code is : " + resp.status.toString())
    log.warn("response is : " + resp.getEntity().getContent().getText())
   }
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Exceptiion while request" + e)
    }
```

I get resp code 200 but on the other side they get JSON like this and can't parse it because of "valueCount", "strings" and "bytes":

```json
{
    "request": {
        "token": {
            "valueCount": 1,
            "strings": ["", ""],
            "bytes": [85, 69, 108, 112, 108, 120, 90, 99, 113, 107, 100, 106, 71, 108, 121, 102, 199, 115, 103, 107, 33, 45, 109, 70, 37, 65, 91, 33, 47, 77, 54, 83, 111, 115, 77, 49, 77, 50, 107, 74, 65,  122],
            "values": ["token"]
        },
        "commonData": {
            "taskId": {
                "valueCount": 1,
                "strings": ["", ""],
                "bytes": [48, 49, 55, 56, 56],
                "values": ["here is issue id"]
            }
        },
        "phonesData": {
            "phone": {
                "valueCount": 1,
                "strings": ["", ""],
                "bytes": [43, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48],
                "values": ["+01234567890"]
            },
            "phoneType": 1
        },
        "addData": {
            "title": {
                "valueCount": 1,
                "strings": ["", ""],
                "bytes": [84, 101, 115, 116],
                "values": ["Test"]
            },
            "description": {
                "valueCount": 1,
                "strings": ["", ""],
                "bytes": [-113, -48, -78, -48, -70, -48, -80, 32, -48, -76, -48, -69, -47, -113, 32, -48, -102, -48, -90, 32, -48, -98, -48, -73, -48, -66, -48, -67, 46],
                "values": ["here is issue summary"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is why they get that parameters and what I have to do not to send that "valueCount", "strings" and "bytes"?
Thanks to any help

Comment: Have you tried with e.g. `"${issue.summary}".toString()` instead?

Comment: What @cfrick said + you might want to try that on all the GString values in the json structure. Once you write `"${something}"`, the resulting object will be of class `GString` which seems to mess up the json serialization.

Comment: That's what i meant: the toString() forces a string (and toString inside the var of a Gstring is useless anyway).

Comment: do NOT use string interpolation here. Instead of `"taskId":"${issue.id.toString()}"` use `"taskId":issue.id`

Answer (score 2):

The serializer in some versions of Camel does not recognise GString type.
Hence, you would need to force conversion to string by calling toString()

def v_stringvar = "${var1} text ${var2}";

And then you use it in this way

v_stringvar?.toString()